# AJAX not rendering as it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, jbuilder

I am at a loss with what’s stopping my code not rendering AJAX where it should be, I have a less serious JS ‘Parse error’ which I can’t work out also.

I have a default prevented rails form_for where upon submit event jQuery finds the element and its attribute values, posts them to the model via appropriate action, model then responds with the new object and is supposed to render the JSON  via a jbuilder form.

All is fine when I  get the page to render via a redirect, but not by a render ‘create’, content_type: :json, error displayed is  a missing template error. I also see from network response that it ‘failed to load response data’.  views/reviews/create.json.jbuilder is saved is in the correct place I believe, class and id names are all correct I believe, files and folders are named correctly and in the right place I believe, I can’t see anything wrong? Unsure whether it’s a jbuilder error, a controller syntax error, or a jQuery syntax error. Here is my code:

**controllers/reviews_controller.rb:**

```
def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @review = @restaurant.reviews.new(params[:review].permit(:thoughts, :rating))

    if @restaurant.reviews.find_by user_id: current_user.id
      flash[:notice] = "You already reviewed this restaurant!" 
      redirect_to restaurants_path
    else
      @review.user = current_user
      @review.save 
      # redirect_to restaurants_path, will do a redirect, but defeats AJAX purpose!
      render 'create', content_type: :json # results in a missing template error #'missing templete reviews/create' error
    end
  end
```

**Assets/restaurants/restaurants.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.new_review').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var reviewList = $(this).siblings('ul');
    var currentRestaurant = $(this).parent();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(review){
      if review # This line results in Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier
      var newReview = Mustache.render($('#review_template').html(), review);
        reviewList.append(newReview);

        currentRestaurant.find('.review_count').text(review.restaurant.review_count)
        currentRestaurant.find('.average_rating_number').text(review.restaurant.average_rating);
        currentRestaurant.find('.average_rating_stars').text(review.restaurant.average_rating_stars);
    }, 'json');
  });
});
```

**views/restaurants/index.html.erb (jbuilder template element):**

```
<template id='review_template'>
  <li>
    <strong>{{ star_rating }}</strong> -*- {{ thoughts }}
  </li>
</template>
```

**views/reviews/create.json.jbuilder:**

```
json.thoughts @review.thoughts
json.star_rating star_rating(@review.rating)

json.restaurant do
  json.average_rating number_with_precision(@restaurant.average_rating,
  precision: 1)
  json.average_rating_stars star_rating(@restaurant.average_rating)
  json.review_count pluralize(@restaurant.reviews.count, 'reviews')
end
```

Been on this for hours now trying to solve this one, pfff!! any idea where I’m going wrong folks? Am I doing something really dim somewhere here? Thank you.

Comment: Can you give the error message sent by the server if there is one?

Comment: The exact error message is: Missing template reviews/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/james/Makers/week8/yelp/app/views" * "/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"

Comment: However the jbuilder template is there, views/reviews/create.json.jbuilder. Note that the network response in chrome console, when using the redirect '/restaurants' syntax (commented out above) loads no data. When using redirect '/restaurants' the object is created, and is displayed via a full page refresh. Just not being displayed via json.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error message, rails is looking for a file called `reviews/create[extension]` or `application/create[extension]` and extensions allowed are `.erb, .builder, .raw, .ruby, .coffee or .jbuilder`.

I suggest to change you ajax call to ask for js, not json, create a file called `reviews/create.js.erb`, and add this kind of code :

```
<% if @restaurant.reviews.find_by user_id: current_user.id %>
  // do the code to show the error message in javascript
<% else %>
  reviewList.append("<%= j(render('create')) %>");
  currentRestaurant.find('.review_count').text(<%= pluralize(@restaurant.reviews.count, 'reviews') %>)
  currentRestaurant.find('.average_rating_number').text(<%= number_with_precision(@restaurant.average_rating, precision: 1) %>);
  currentRestaurant.find('.average_rating_stars').text(<%=star_rating(@restaurant.average_rating) %>);
<% end %>
```

This code should be executed after the success of the creation. You also have to create a file called `reviews/_create.html.erb` with the html you want to show. Finally, you have to delete some logic in  the javascript and in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Dougui. With lots of playing around I have now completely isolated this to the if statement in the restaurants.js file(7th line down). Whilst removing the if statement everything returns to operating via JS/AJAX as it should. The only thing i need to solve is the conditional statement in the restaurants.js so that it does not do the Mustache render if current_user already has already created a review object in the restaurants model. I think it maybe that the conditional statement needs to in a function of it's own. Any suggestions as to how i correctly do this?

Comment: You should have a value in the returned data that said if there is a review or not. I prefer to have the callback in the `.js.erb` file but it's as you wish.